# Организация поддоменов .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, php

Здравствуйте, нужно организовать динамические поддомены что-то вроде msk.site.ru spb.site.ru и так далее
Думал сделать через секцию VirtualHost, но хостер запретил это делать
Смотрите, допустим пользователь обратился к поддомену xxx.site.ru когда он зашёл на этот поддомен идёт запрос допустим на файл city.php?name=xxx
Как организовать подобное на .htaccess?

Comment: используйте %{HTTP_HOST} в RewriteCond

Comment: @eicto а пример не могли бы привести?

Comment: @АЛСУ, трудно пример приводить тому, кто на `%{HTTP_HOST} в RewriteCond` просит пример. Если нет базовых понятий, то `%{HTTP_HOST} в RewriteCond` не поможет. Немного почитайте матчасть.